# Converting a byte array to image in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to get a image from my REST API service however haven't found any documentation on how to decode the response body that would be a byte array to an image in Flutter? Anyone with some useful resources, please help...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use this for your image widget: Image.memory(bytes). You can [find more documentation on the Flutter dev website](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/Image.memory.html).

Comment: Thank you I must of skipped over this when looking.

Comment: Hi how can I decode raw image byte array? that function says "This only accepts compressed image formats (e.g. PNG). Uncompressed
formats like rawRgba (the default format of [ui.Image.toByteData]) will
lead to exceptions."

Answer (score 9):

Since top rated answer use flutter/widget.dart, this use `dart:ui` only

```dart
Future<Image> tinypng() async {
  final bytes = Uint8List.fromList([
    137, 80, 78, 71, 13, 10, 26, 10, 0, 0, 0, 13, 73, 72, 68, 82, 0, 0, 0,
    1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 8, 6, 0, 0, 0, 31, 21, 196, 137, 0, 0, 0, 10, 73, 68, 65,
    84, 120, 156, 99, 0, 1, 0, 0, 5, 0, 1, 13, 10, 45, 180, 0, 0, 0, 0, 73,
    69, 78, 68, 174, 66, 96, 130 // prevent dartfmt
  ]);

  // copy from decodeImageFromList of package:flutter/painting.dart
  final codec = await instantiateImageCodec(bytes);
  final frameInfo = await codec.getNextFrame();
  return frameInfo.image;
}
```

Comment: `getNextFrame()` method is inaccessible in Flutter 2.0.5

Answer (score 6):

This will return a Widget

```
Image.memory(Uint8List);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Container(
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .2,
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .9,
  
  child:Image.memory(
    base64.decode(controlleR.offersList[index].pictureEn.toString()),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?