# How to convert bytes into image in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm developing a Flutter app, in which i need to display image form bytes.

Here is the JSON response I'm getting.

```
{
"result": {
    "reF_ID": 140,
    "filE_BYTES": "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"
},
    "targetUrl": null,
    "success": true,
    "error": null,
    "unAuthorizedRequest": false,
    "__abp": true
}
```

Here is app side code,

```
Future<String> getPanPhoto() async {
    var res = await http.get(
        Uri.encodeFull(getPanPhotoUrl),
        headers: {
            "Content-type": "application/json",
            "Accept": "application/json"
        },
    );
    var photoResponse = json.decode(res.body);
    Map<String, dynamic> result = photoResponse['result'];
    String success = photoResponse['success'].toString();
    if (success == "true") {
        String refId = result['reF_ID'].toString();
        var imageResponse = result['filE_BYTES'];
        _base64 = BASE64.encode(imageResponse.toString());
        Uint8List bytes = BASE64.decode(imageResponse.bodybytes);
    }

    setState(() {
        _photoFile = bytes as File;
    });

    print(res.statusCode);
    print(res.body);
}
```

I want to display image into this

```
return Container(
    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
        top: 10.0,
        bottom: 10.0,
    ),
    child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
        child: Image.memory(bytes),
    ),
);
```

While calling this, I got error as,

> Exception has occurred. NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The method 'encode' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: encode('')

Comment: The error makes it clear that you are calling `encode` on a null object.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting a byte array to image in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55314081/converting-a-byte-array-to-image-in-flutter)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convert bytes to image is simple one line code :

Image.memory(base64Decode("put your base 64 string"));

Comment: Thank you. It works. And you have any idea how it deals with video? I'm asking how to convert bytes to video in Flutter?

Comment: i dont get anything when i do that. I get a white empty space

Answer (score 2):

You can convert bytes to image in flutter.
Here is how you can covert it:

```
Image.memory(base64Decode("base64 string"));
```

Comment: i dont get anything when i do that. I get a white empty space